# get UserName without the 20 char Limit

Tags: c#, windowsdomainaccount

I have to read the user log in my app even with run as and the name created in domain in windows server 2012have 23 char,
i used :

```
Environment.UserName


new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Identity.Name;

System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

but all this give me the name without the 3 last char
I used :

```
UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName
UserPrincipal.Current.Name
```

but give me the displayed name

how can i get the full length login name

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard limit on the samAccountName property:

> "You can't modify the length of the user's samAccountName, it is a
>   defined value within the schema and is set to 20."

See: [this page for source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/63d2795c-8c28-4a22-9820-18190bfcdcf9/not-able-to-create-username-having-more-than-20-characters-in-active-directory?forum=winserverDS)

Maybe you could try the `UserPrincipalname`

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current().UserPrincipalName
```

you need to add a reference to the `AccountManagement` Namespace

Comment: the user have been created in domain with UserName@Domain and the UserName lenght is 23 and I have to read it

Comment: I used it but give me the displayed name